# Command to list PostgreSQL user accounts?

Tags: users, postgresql

There are `createuser` & `dropuser` commands:

```
createuser - define a new PostgreSQL user account
dropuser - remove a PostgreSQL user account
```

Is there a corresponding way to list the user accounts?

These two commands do not require the user to invoke `psql` nor understand details of using it.

Answer (score 143):

Use the `psql` shell and:

`\deu[+] [PATTERN]` such as:

```
postgres=# \deu+
      List of user mappings
 Server | User name | FDW Options 
--------+-----------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

And for all users:

```
postgres=# \du 
                              List of roles
 Role name  |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 chpert.net |                                                | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Also such as MySQL, you can do :

```
$ psql -c "\du"
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 chpert    |                                                | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 test      |                                                | {}
```

Comment: from terminal: `psql -c '\du'`

Answer (score 12):

To limit the output to the username only, simply do the following either from the `psql` shell or from the local shell/terminal as

```
psql -c "SELECT u.usename AS "User Name" FROM pg_catalog.pg_user u;"
```

While the quick method, as pointed out in a previous answer, displays 3 columns; including **User Name**, **List of Roles Attributes**, and **Member of** role group(s).

```
psql -c "\du"
```

Finally, as pointed out in a subsequent answer, the PostgreSQL commands run in the background for the `\du` command show those "default" columns by calling:

```
SELECT u.usename AS "User name",
  u.usesysid AS "User ID",
  CASE WHEN u.usesuper AND u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('superuser, create
database' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usesuper THEN CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('create database' AS
pg_catalog.text)
       ELSE CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
  END AS "Attributes"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user u
ORDER BY 1;
```

> (what psql does behind the scenes when you type \du)

The last part was copied from the [PostgreSQL Mailing List](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1121195544.8208.242.camel@state.g2switchworks.com).

Answer (score 5):

For a simpler answer...

From within psql:

```
\du
```

From the terminal:

```
psql -c '\du'
```

It helps me to remember that **d** is often used to **d**escribe something and **u** is for **u**sers.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Solution which is normally done by psql \du:

```
SELECT u.usename AS "User name",
  u.usesysid AS "User ID",
  CASE WHEN u.usesuper AND u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('superuser, create
database' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usesuper THEN CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('create database' AS
pg_catalog.text)
       ELSE CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
  END AS "Attributes"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user u
ORDER BY 1;
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1121195544.8208.242.camel@state.g2switchworks.com